# Shifting charecters in a given string

Tags: java

```
char ch = (char) (((int) text.charAt(i) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97);
```

`shift` is a number. To move the characters in a string
please explain this line. In Which order it's executing.

Comment: What do _you_ think the order is? Java expressions are left-to-right taking into account any grouping by parentheses and operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

The following code result `ch` to `'f'`

```
String text = "a";
int i = 0;
int shift = 5;
char ch = (char) (((int) text.charAt(i) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97);
```

Steps

```
text.charAt(i) == 'a'
'a' + shift    == 97 + 5 == 102
102 - 97       == 5
5 % 26         == 5
5 + 97         == 102
(char) 102     == 'f'
```

---

`int > char` and `char > int` are done with ASCII table

Comment: Why---> 5%97  In expression there is %26+97 right.. Could you explain that logic..

Comment: @Reddy fixed sorry